# Time complexity of a code with a for loop in return statement

Tags: python, performance

what would be the time complexity with respect to N(total no. of elements)?

functions flatten the nested list of integers (List[List[int]]) into a single list and remove duplicates by leaving only the first occurrences.

```
def f2(list_of_list):
    flat_list = []
    for inner_list in list_of_list:
        flat_list.extend(inner_list)
    return [
        x for i, x in enumerate(flat_list)
        if flat_list.index(x) == i]
```

Comment: could you reformat your code in a code block with proper indentation?

Comment: best case it is O(n^2)

Comment: What is the point of `if flat_list.index(x) == i`??? Anyway, your code is quadratic time on the total number of elements in the flattened list. But that is because you are calling `if flat_list.index(x) == i` in the loop. But *why are you doing this*? Is it to get unique elements in the list? There are more performant ways to do that, making your code linear time

Comment: Complexity *in terms of what*? "O(N)" doesn't mean anything without a specification of how N relates to the problem being solved. Also, what is the *problem you are trying to solve here*? Are you trying to give the correct answer to a homework question? Make predictions about how long the code will take on a "real-world" data set based on test results? Look for a better algorithm? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of your code would be `O(n)` (`n` is the length of `flat_list`). First, find the most time complex top-level loop. That would be the first loop. Then, the first loop appends all the elements of the lists to `flat_list`, so the loop is run the number of elements in `flat_list`.

Comment: Why are you saying it is O(N**2) based on the first loop? What is N here? The first loop is *linear time* on the total number of elements in the flattened list

Comment: As an aside, trying to get unique elements is probably what the OP is doing, but using `list(set(flat_list))` is not equivalent, because it would affect the order of the resulting list

Answer (score 0):

**list.extend()** has a time complexity of O(k) where k is the length of the list being used as the extension.

**list.index()** has a time complexity of O(n) in the worst case scenario (value is last element or not in the list)

n = the number of lists in the list_of_lists
m = the total number of elements in all of the lists.

Then the time complexity of the list comprehension will be *at best* **O(m)** when every element is identical (making list.index(x) essentially constant time as it always returns 0)

*At worst*, when every element is unique, it will be  **O(m<sup>2</sup>)**.

The first loop is a linear O(m), as m would be the sum of each k for every call to flat_list.extend()